# Select specified template for each post

Tags: wordpress

When creating **Pages** it's possible to select specified template for each page.

Is there this feature for **Posts**? Or we must do it manually?

Is there a **plugin** for this purpose?

Comment: A good plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-template/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

For posts there is a *sort of* **only slightly** similar thing called "post formats". [image]

Like page template, this too is dependent on whether theme supports them or not.
A major point of difference between page templates and post formats is page templates **generally** offer features like choosing between left sidebar , right sidebar, multiple sidebars (or no sidebar at all), blank page and full -width page.
The post formats on the other hand dont provide features to change the layout of the page, but most deal with changing the positioning and layout of the featured image and the post content.